# Selection of one tab should be removed while creating new tab in react js

Tags: reactjs

How to remove the selection of tab when we add or create a new tab. Here the selection off tab still remain same while creating new tab..

Comment: Please add more details like the sample code that you have tried and the issue you are facing

Comment: Which tab? Browser's tab or tabs that you created yourself? Also what software stack currently you're using? Is it bootstrap or Material or other?